# Julia: Affine Transformations with Compose module

Tags: julia

Is it possible to transform images (as shown below) via matrices with [Compose.jl](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Compose.jl)? 
If so, could you please provide a simple example?

I'm aware of the `rotation` keyword argument in the `Compose.context` method, but I was wondering if there was something similar for general affine transformations. Thanks!

[image: shear transformation]

Comment: This seems to be an open feature request: [Compose.jl#115](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Compose.jl/issues/115).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Shear`. For example, you can transform

[image]

from the tutorials (code below)

```
julia> composition = compose(context(),
               (context(units=UnitBox(0, 0, 1000, 1000)),
                polygon([(0, 1000), (500, 1000), (500, 0)]),
                fill("tomato")),
               (context(),
                polygon([(1, 1), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 0)]),
                fill("bisque")))
```

and shear it with

```
julia> composition_sheared = compose(context(shear=Shear(0.3,0.0,0.5,1.0)),
               (context(units=UnitBox(0, 0, 1000, 1000)),
                polygon([(0, 1000), (500, 1000), (500, 0)]),
                fill("tomato")),
               (context(),
                polygon([(1, 1), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 0)]),
                fill("bisque")))
```

to obtain

[image]